# jQuery DataTables how to disable sorting when clicking on table header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a question regarding `jQuery DataTables`.I have the following situation , when table is loading everything should be sorted by third column , but at the same time , I  sorting by columns should be disabled (when clicking on the header of the table),  and  highlighting of column on which sorting is done should be also disabled.

Please if you have any idea , share it with me.
Thank You.

Comment: a quick google search turns up lots of results for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`order`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/order) option to define initial sorting along with [`columnDefs.orderable`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable) set to `false` to disable sorting for specific columns and [`columnDefs.targets`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) set to `_all` to target all columns.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   order: [[2, 'asc']],
   columnDefs: [{
      targets: "_all",
      orderable: false
   }]
});
```

If you don't want the sorted column to be higlighted use the following classes for your table: `stripe hover row-border`, see the HTML example below:

```
<table id="example" class="stripe hover row-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygsLtker/) for code and demonstration.